# how to establish a many to many relationship with itself of a table in cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data-modeling, database, nosql

Actually i am working on app in which a user table can have many to many relationship with itself.

It is an app in which a particular user can sell things to different buyers and can buy things from different sellers.
that is,a particular user can have many buyers and many sellers.

As a user is selling things to some other user.
User becomes seller for that particular user & that particular user become the buyer of that user.

I am very new to cassandra and i do not how relationships work in cassandra.

Could AnyOne tell me what should i do to establish that relationship

My User table is as follows :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id text,
    login text,
    password text,
    firstName text,
    lastName text,
    gender text,
    mobileNo text,
    aadhar text,
    email text,
    stateCode text,
    district text,
    city text,
    zipCode int,
    address text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: List all type of your query you want to execute. In Cassandra table are design based on select query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is a NoSQL database and one particular character of it is regarding storing unstructured data. So, you should not think about relations of tables, instead, think of how would you like to get this information (in other words, what would be your "select * from" fields).

You should to take a look at [this cassandra data modeling introduction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/dataModelingApproach.html);

After that, you will notice 2 things:

1. Primary keys plays a HUGE role on cassandra storage
2. You can only filter searches (where clause) using primary keys

You are looking for is to have one table for each search cql:

```
create table sells_by_user_id (
user_id text,
buyer_id text,
date timestamp,
item text,
item_description,
..., <this will depend on which info you would like to obtain
primary key ((user_id), date)); //with this table you will obtain all the things that a user sold and to whom

create table buys_by_user_id (
user_id text,
seller_id text,
date timestamp,
item text,
item_description,
..., <this will depend on which info you would like to obtain
primary key ((user_id), date)); //this table will store all things that an user bought
```

As you can see, its a different mindset of traditional RDBMS.

Another example:
create table transactions_by_item_name (
    item_name text,
    seller_id text,
    seller_name text,
    buyer_id text,
    buyer_name text,
    date timestamp,
    item text,
    item_description,
    ...,

To accomplish atomic transactions on your writes (as you will probably have to write same info in more than one table) is to use [batch statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html)

Comment: I will work on it and will try to see whether it fits in my app